# System Set Permissions Accidentally, and is Corrupt

Tags: system, file-permissions, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

My phone's system folder at `/system` was corrupt.  I accidentally set its permissions to `rw-r--r--`.  Then, I reboot my phone, and nothing is working.
Here's what I mean:

1. 1st reboot: power off;
2. 2nd *automatic* reboot: automatically went to Recovery Mode;

When I reboot, it doesn't go to the Operating System.  It just sends me to Recovery Mode.

Offline Charging is (I think) also not available.  It powers on the device, but it doesn't play the Boot Animation (because the System Folder is corrupt), so it just send me to Recovery Mode.

What should I do?  How could I set the permissions of the system folder back to its default state `rwxr-xr-x`?

I had think of 3 possible ways:

1. `chmod` the system folder using TWRP Recovery's Built - in chmod.

   - I need to find the "Octal Code" of the permission `rwxr-xr-x`.
2. Install the stock ROM (in this case, CM 12.1) through recovery.

   - I don't know if this one will work.
3. Wipe the System Partition, and install the ROM.

   - I have no idea if this will work, or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved quickly after digging on TWRP, and found out that there is a restore option.

Luckily, I have a backup of the System Partition.

The ROM installed on my device was CM 12.1, which is running Android 5.1 Lollipop.

The backup system (pre - installed ROM) was the stock ROM, which is running Android 4.4 Kitkat.

Guess I should just install that CM ROM.

By the way, I could get into the Operating System now, but I have another problem, which I will post in an [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171941/bootloop-after-system-restore).

Comment: Just in case you don't have a backup, the octal for `rwxr-xr-x` is `755`.

Comment: Yes!  That's the Octal Code for `rwxr-xr-x`, and it's already built-in on TWRP `chmod 755`, but nothing happened to me.  I already tried that, but the problem is still not solved.  Luckily, I have a backup of the System partition, so do a Nandroid backup first, especially the System partition, to make sure nothing's lost, and you can restore it easily when problems occur.

Comment: That I do know, and it's always a precious suggestion.