# Bootloop after System Restore

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

My device just got into bootloop after [restoring a backup of the system partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171933/system-set-permissions-accidentally-and-is-corrupt).

This bootloop is just a soft bootloop.  I mean, I could get into the Operating System, but it keeps playing the Boot Animation.

Comment: This is due to different android versions conflict. If you have restored without wiping previous ROM(5.1), it will ends in bootloop. Wiping 5.1 clears all data.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by installing a ROM (in this case, CM13), and the problem is gone.

I still need to wipe and do a Factory Reset, because it came from another ROM.

After wiping, the ROM should install, and you could now get to the Operating System.